# When is it required to return a reference from a function?

Tags: c++

My question is when does any one need to return an object by reference? Well this comes from the fact that we can as well pass the object to be filled through the parameter list itself. Are there any particular scenarios where it mandates the return by reference.

I'm asking this with respect to non member functions.

Edit: I'm aware of its usage in operator overloading.

Comment: Sorry - having trouble following "Well this comes from the fact that we can as well pass the object to be filled through the parameter list itself."  Can you illustrate the alternatives you're talking about?

Comment: @Tony: This is what my intention was: `std::string& getName();` is the return by reference way. Where as the below method takes a reference to an already created string and fills it with the output value -> `void getName(std::string& fillName);` Hope this clarifies your concern.

Comment: @Pernima: there's a fundamental different in ownershp of the string though, as `getName()` has to "find" a `std::string` somewhere to return a reference to, while `getName(std::string&)` is being told which `string` to use by the caller, so they're not really alternatives. In that light - "when does one need to return an object by reference?"... when the called function, and not the caller, knows where the object is... ;-).

Comment: The two alternatives are not the same by any means. Returning *by value* can be compared to *pass by reference and fill internally*: in both cases the objective is to provide an object to the caller. But returning *by reference* has many uses that do not involve copying, like calling member methods that might modify the internal state of the object.

Comment: @Tony: :) Well yes. @David: Yes I'm aware of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return as reference when you want the reveiving end to have access to the referred object. Consider `operator[]` in a map and the use case:

```
std::map<std::string, int> word_count;
std::string word;
while ( std::cin >> word ) {
   word_count[ word ]++;
}
```

You do not want to extract the value from the map, but rather *access* the stored object in this case to modify it. The same goes with many other designs, where you need access to some internal data, but you do not want to copy it:

```
if ( person.name() == "Pete" ) {
```

The user does not need to copy the object, only to check whether the object has a concrete value. You could have forced a copy by returning by value, and the semantics would be the same, but with higher costs. Or you could create a local variable and pass it by reference to a function that will fill it, in which case you are not only incurring the cost of copying, but also making code more cumbersome:

```
std::string name;
person.fill_name( name );
if ( name == "Pete" ) {
```

Which, as you can probably notice, is much more cumbersome in all uses of the member function.

Now, I see the "I'm asking this with non-member functions", well, the same rationale applies at different levels. Free standing functions can be applied to objects, consider:

```
boost::any any = 5;
boost::any_cast<int&>( any )++;
```

The function `any_cast` is a free function and yet it returns a *reference* to another instance. If you need access to the actual object and not a copy, then a reference is the solution. Note that for only reading you don't need a reference and you may as well return by value:

```
std::cout << boost::any_cast<int>( any );   // will print 6 now
```

Similarly in all cases where the function returns references to objects that are not arguments, but globals or `static` (returning a reference to a variable with auto storage in a function is undefined behavior, but in all cases where it is correct to do so the semantics would not be the same if you change it with any other solution.

Comment: +1 already, but deserves another +1 for the nice example of `boost::any`.  Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

When returning a reference to an object that exists elsewhere, for example a `find` function searching a table.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use it for a singleton (static object that is created once, and released after the `main()`. For example :

```
struct A
{
   unsigned int veryLongTable[ 1000 ];
};

const A& GetTable()
{
  static A *table = NULL;
  if ( NULL == table )
  {
    table = new A;
    // write values
  }
  return *table;
}
```

Comment: How's that improve on simply `const A& GetTable() { static A table; return A; }`...? AFAIK, static members aren't constructed until the function's invoked anyway, so it's already lazy, and with some compilers & command-line options (e.g. GCC) the simpler version's thread-safe to boot....  +1 for covering static locals and singleton's though - I can abandon my answer :-).

Comment: @Tony The problem with the suggestion in your comment is that you can not change the values, because the function returns a const reference.

Comment: yes - fingers got away from me - `A& GetTable() { static A table; return A; }...?` then?  But looking at your answer again, I note the `//write values`: your version does make it easier to update `table` if the constructor doesn't allow it to be created in the desired state... fair enough.

Comment: @Tony, @VJo: You can in fact do that change and update the values in the table in exactly the same way, but you will need an extra `static bool first_pass = true;` variable so that you can distinguish when we are in the first pass and initialize and avoid initializing in all other circumstances. This code is broken in multithreaded code anyway (both solutions, if you need to initialize, unless you move initialization to a helper function). Another note is that the code in the answer *leaks* memory when the program exits. This might not be an issue in most cases though.

Comment: @David: yes, an extra bool is possible but unfortunate. "broken in multithreaded code"... again, my claim was only "with some compilers & command-line options (e.g. GCC)" (and I stand by it). Re leaks memory - whether it leaks is a matter of definition, as the OS will reclaim it, but it's a strong point in general as if `A` e.g. used shared memory, locks therein, or was meant to affect an orderly sign off from a network service, then a failure to invoke the destructor could have a tangible effect.

Answer (score 0):

Emphasis mine in quotes

> we can as well *pass* the object

- What if the type is not default constructible?
- What if it is not constructible at all?
- What if it is constructible but extremely expensive to do so?

> the object *to be filled*

You got it wrong: a function that returns *by value* can be equivalent to a function that uses a reference out parameter, but it's **not** equivalent to a function that returns *a reference*. To wit:

```
T& f();
void f(T&);

// We're not filling anything at all!
f().some_member();
f( ??? );
```

Comment: You either understand the questioner's concerns much better than me, or much worse, but I can't work out which. ;-/

Comment: @Tony For the second point, David Rodríguez is much more eloquent than me on the subject.

Comment: Well, I've followed everying David's said so far, so I'll not worry too much.  Cheers.